# Saving and displaying textfield.text

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, plist

i am having a tableview with a list of categories.i have an add button which pops an alertview with a textfield.and the text entered in that field should appear in the tableview.everything is fine till here.but it is not getting saved.guess i need to add it to the plist programmatically.can someone help me with it?

```
//Reading data from plist.
NSString *categoryFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Categories" ofType:@"plist"];
self.categoryList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:categoryFile];


//adding to the tableView
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(buttonIndex == 1)
{
    UITextField *newCategoryName = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    NSInteger section = 0;
    NSInteger row = 0;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
    NSString *extraContent = newCategoryName.text;
    [[self categoryList]insertObject:extraContent atIndex:row];
    NSArray *indexPathsToInsert = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
    [[self tableOfCategories]insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    NSLog(@"%@",newCategoryName.text);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the file is located inside your app bundle, then you are not going to be able to save to it

So you will need to save the new array in the Documents Directory

Add the following to your code

```
//First change your load code to the following
//try to load the file from the document directory
NSString *categoryFile = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Categories"];

//if no file there, load from bundle
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:categoryFile])
{
    categoryFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Categories" ofType:@"plist"];
}
//Load the array
self.categoryList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:categoryFile];

... after adding a new category

[[self categoryList]insertObject:extraContent atIndex:row];
//After adding the new element, save array
[self.categoryList writeToFile: categoryFile atomically:YES];
```

This will save the new category to the original file

Comment: its working but if i run the code again i am not able to see it.

Comment: you are not able to see what?

Comment: thank you veru much its working.u saved my day.should we use the same process for deleting also??.